# Flash IDE - Find a symbol in the library

Tags: flash, ide

I've inherited a flash project (my first) that has many existing symbols in the library. They are organized in a large complex hierarchy of folders. Often, I find a reference to a symbol in actionscript code, but can't find the symbol in the library. The "Find" feature only searches for instances of a symbol. If none exist, is it possible to find a symbol in the library without manually checking each folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be helpful
http://www.gskinner.com/products/panelpack1/gSearch.php